# Detecting varying time rates

Tags: time-series

I was thinking about detecting the veracity of user ratings by examining the time-stamp. Basically I have a series of times $(t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n)$. So assuming that ratings should normally come in at a constant rate, is there a good way to detect whether some time-stamps are unusually clumped up, because a set of consecutive fake ratings was injected over a short period of time?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest looking into the [Poisson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) distribution. Of course, the problem is that there may be legitimate reasons for bursts of ratings: a blog article on the product causing a surge in interest and hence a surge in raters, etc, so this doesn't prove fraud.

Comment: Ideally I'd have one total static of how ordinary a set of timestamps is - no need for detecting where outliers really are. How would I apply Poisson in this case? Find the Poisson rate over all samples and then use a sliding window to detect unusually dense clusters?

Comment: Yes, you have a sliding window of time and look at how many events occur in the window. If the usual average is 100, `qpois (0.975, 100)` is 120, and `qpois (0.025, 100)` is 81, which says that more than 120 or fewer than 81 events in the window is "suspicious" (at the 95% level of confidence).

Answer (score 1):

If you assume a stable rate, then you can model the time between ratings as an exponential function with constant parameter. The parameter can be estimated from actual data.

From that point, I guess it is possible to predict when (according to your model) a rating would be expected in new data. Any deviation from the prediction might be interpreted as a fake rating.

I'm not sure of how I would implement the idea, but maybe you can take this approach as it seems rather simple.

Comment: It is *certain* that the actual time of a rating will deviate from a single predicted value. For your recommendation to have any value, then, you would need to explain how to predict a useful *interval* of times.

Comment: Matching an exponential distribution against all intervals seems interesting. What is an appropriate test for that? I don't understand the comment of whuber. Will it give me correct results for my task?

Answer (score 1):

Your series of times are simply transactions. What you want to do is "bucket" thewe transactions to create a time series e.g. 15 minute buckets or 1 hour buckets. Now that you have a time series you can develop a model that captures/explains the typical expectations. Violations of these expectataions may suggest Pulses or Temporary level shifts or local time trends. The time series may be impacted by day-of-the-week or known events (an ad for example) . Bringing in these possible predictor/exogenous variables can then reduce the number of unusal values providing clarity to the truly unusual.